# Equivalence of Context-Free-Grammar and Context-Free-Grammar in CNF

Tags: formal-languages, context-free, formal-grammars

- Given any *Context-Free-Grammar, $G$*, and another in *Chomsky Normal Form, $G_c$*, how can we check if both $G$ and $G_c$ generate the same language?

One of the trivial ways I know of is to convert $G$ into a CNF form. which motivates my second question,

- Can two different *Context-Free-Grammars* in CNF, $G_c$ and $G_c^\prime$, generate the same language? (I would appreciate a proof of it)

Comment: Equivalence of CFGs is undecidable.

Answer (score 4):

Chomsky normal forms are not unique. If they were, we'd have an algorithm for deciding whether two CF grammars are equal. But equivalence of CF grammars is undecidable.

Answer (score 1):

Compare
$$\begin{align}S &\to AB \\
B &\to BB \\
A &\to a \\
B &\to b\end{align}$$
With
$$\begin{align}S &\to AB \\
A &\to AB \\
A &\to a \\
B &\to b
\end{align}$$
By what comparison would these grammars be equal?

Comment: As for the first question, see [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Context-free_grammar#Language_equality).